# How to use uwsgi to batch HTTP requests to send to SQS?

Tags: python, nginx, uwsgi

I'm trying to log HTTP requests from nginx that come into uwsgi and put them on SQS but I'm not sure how to exactly go about doing it because uwsgi has so many components!

There's the LIFO/FIFO queue, which is circular so I might lose data if I don't empty the queue fast enough.

There's the caching framework, which... doesn't sound like the right fit to the problem.

There's the spooler, which sounds like it might do what I want it to, except it seems to create many little files for each entry in the filesystem.

There are mules, which can probably do the actual work of checking if the list is full enough, flushing a list if it looks like it's taking too long to fill up, actually sending the list to SQS via boto, but is that what the spooler is for?

Can anybody explain how these components are supposed to be used in a uWSGI deployment? Especially in this particular use case?

Comment: I think you should reduce your question so that it's easy to understand what you're asking

Comment: OK I reduced the question

Comment: Why don't you make an API endpoint, instead of using the log? I've never heard anybody use nginx or apache2 log, parse them and assign jobs.

Comment: Well, the system involves Piwik, and past a certain number of hits per day (like a couple million) it's better to buffer up HTTP requests and batch insert them later. Otherwise you have to worry about keeping the API up when a huge load of visits hits...

This uwsgi solution is intermediate - instead of a once per day batch insert of HTTP requests, or a continuous torrent of HTTP requests, you buffer them and send them all at once every few minutes or so.